# Can priority queue be made by using simple queues

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

Is priority queue just a sorted queue? Can it be made by creating a simple queue and sorting it afterwards?
**https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-priority-queue-and-a-queue?share=1** I found this link and it states that they priority queue can be made by *Re-arrange the Queue at insertion time, and put the recently inserted object at the appropriate priority place*. I wanted to be certain about it because some of my peers stated that its not possible, but if we make a queue which adheres to priority, wouldn't it make the queue a priority queue?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: Did you do any research? What did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) is an abstract data-structure with a few required operations:

- check emptiness (`is_empty`);
- insert element by "priority" (`insert`);
- find and remove the element with the highest priority (`pop`).

There are many way to implement this, but you are usually looking for a `O(log n)` (amortized) complexity for both `pop` and `insert`.

A [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) is an abstract data-structure where you insert at the back and remove at the front, so it cannot be used to implement a priority queue (there is  no "ordering", except first-in first-out).

The simplest way to implement a priority queue is usually to use a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). A minimalist C++ implementation using a `std::vector<int>` as a backend and the [heap operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm#Heap_operations) defined in the standard library could be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using priority_queue = std::vector<int>;

bool is_empty(priority_queue const& q) { return q.empty(); }

void insert(priority_queue &q, int value) { 
    q.push_back(value);
    std::push_heap(std::begin(q), std::end(q));
}

int pop(priority_queue &q) {
    std::pop_heap(std::begin(q), std::end(q));
    const int value = q.back();
    q.pop_back();
    return value;
}
```

This gives you (amortized) `O(log n)` complexity for both `insert` and `pop`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much.

You can't "sort" a standard queue because it does not have random access. A `std::priority_queue` is usually backed by a vector.

It just does the "automatic sorting" for you, is all. You wouldn't actually re-sort the whole thing (which would do a lot of pointless comparisons): you'd do a lower/upper bound search for a position to insert your new element. Removal can be similarly specialised, because you know the elements are sorted so can do a binary search.

But the end result is a thing that behaves much like a queue, yes.